# HP Load Runner - Version 12.55 - Step Download Error - for 1, 101 and 201 Vusers

Tags: loadrunner

I'm trying to execute HTML/HTTP protocol for 300 concurrent Vusers. And getting "Step Download Timeout Error" for 1st, 101 and 201 Vusers. I've tried the below options.

1. Increased the step download timeout
2. Changed the step download settings to warning instead of error.

Still no luck. Your help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Samithran.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, you can try disabling DEP and UAC using the following links, in case you have them enabled:

a. Disable DEP:
https://softwaresupport.hpe.com/group/softwaresupport/search-result/-/facetsearch/document/KM747283

b. Disable UAC:
https://softwaresupport.hpe.com/group/softwaresupport/search-result/-/facetsearch/document/KM00598473

**Out of curiosity, what are you using to run the Vusers? LR Controller, PC, Stormrunner Load, BPM/BSM?**